# CRX File not downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I have a crx file hosted on a server.
I have a link on my webpage to download it on local machine.

```
<a href="https://example.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx" target="download_frame">Download</a>

<iframe id="download_frame" name="download_frame" src="about:Blank" style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('download_frame').src="https://example.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx";
</script>
```

But on clicking the link, nothing happens. Right Click -> Save downloads the file.

Also,

```
 * window.open("https://example.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx");
 * window.location = "https://example.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx";
 * window.location.href = "https://example.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx";
```

All these three ways open the crx file in same/new webpage as a binary encoded file. And do not download file

Please guide on how to download the file.

Comment: This link is the path to download crx file?. https://test.com/ext/test-1.0.0.crx

Comment: No Anandh, its a private hosted link. Modified the link to a random link address

Comment: It's best to use `example.com` for such purposes; I edited it to make it more clear

Comment: thanks..will keep note of this

Comment: Just to be clear...Do you want to install it or simply download the .crx? If you just want to download it, i could not replicate that behaviour (file download started)..

Comment: I only need to download the crx. The link behaves dead and does nothing on chrome for me

Comment: CViejo could you please elaborate if the same script worked for you on a crx file ?

Comment: Yes. I just uploaded a crx to my server, copied your script, adjusted the paths => worked

Comment: @CViejo Which OS are you using this from? The protection is not active on Linux version.

Comment: @Xan, tested on osx 10.10 and win7. Chrome 44 on both

Comment: @CViejo Hmmm, I can replicate it for Windows for a CRX hosted on Dropbox. Strange.

Comment: @var17 is your html located on same server as the crx file? I think that might be the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove this ambiguity, by adding type identification for crx files, by adding following line in .htaccess file :

```
AddType application/octet-stream crx CRX
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Learnt a lot with your insights